# Problems calling a function that returns an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opengl, glut

I'm trying to program a simple animation using GLUT and OpenGL in c++. I've created three functions for this purpose: `catSpline(), fillArray()`, and `fixedAngle()`. `catSpline()` returns a GLfloat value, `fillArray()` is a void function that consists of a series of loops that fills a series of arrays with GLfloat values produced using catSpline, and `fixedAngle()` will return a 16-unit array. Here is the code for these three methods:

```
GLfloat * fixedAngle(GLfloat initialX, GLfloat initialY, GLfloat initialZ, GLfloat rotX, GLfloat rotY, GLfloat rotZ)

{
      ArrayXXf z(4,4); //initializing the 4x4 rotation matrixes
      ArrayXXf y(4,4);
      ArrayXXf x(4,4);

      x<<1, 0, 0, 0,
          0, cos(rotX), -sin(rotX), 0,
          0, sin(rotX), cos(rotX), 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;

      y<<cos(rotY), 0, sin(rotY), 0,
          0, 1, 0, 0,
          -sin(rotY), 0, cos(rotY), 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;

      z<< cos(rotZ), -sin(rotZ), 0, 0,
          sin(rotZ), cos(rotZ), 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1, 0,
          0, 0, 0, 1;



      ArrayXXf fin(4,4);

      fin = x * y * z; 

      fin(0,3) = initialX;
      fin(1,3) = initialY;
      fin(2,3) = initialZ;
      //now we've moved the translational information into the final matrix
    // std::cout << fin;

     fin(3,3) = 1;

    GLfloat * arr;
    arr = (GLfloat *) malloc(16*sizeof(GLfloat));

          arr[0] = fin(0,0);
         arr[1] = fin(0,1);
         arr[2] = fin(0,2);
         arr[3] = fin(0,3);
        arr[4] = fin(1,0);
        arr[5] = fin(1,1);
            arr[6] = fin(1,2);
        arr[7] = fin(1,3);
                            arr[8] = fin(2,0);
                            arr[9] = fin(2,1);
                            arr[10] = fin(2,2);
                            arr[11] = fin(2,3);
                            arr[12] = fin(3,0);
                            arr[13] = fin(3,1);
                            arr[14] = fin(3,2);
                            arr[15] = fin(3,3);


      return arr; 

}

GLfloat catSpline(GLfloat x1, GLfloat x2, GLfloat x3, GLfloat x4, GLfloat t) 
{ 
    ArrayXXf M(4,4); //4x4 M matrix
    ArrayXXf P(4,1); //matrix to hold keyframe x values 

    P(0,0) = x1;
    P(1,0) = x2;
    P(2,0) = x3;
    P(3,0) = x4;
    //keyframe x values

    M(0,0) = -0.5;
    M(0,1) = 2-(-0.5);
    M(0,2) = -0.5-2;
    M(0,3) = 0.5;

    M(1,0) = 2*0.5;
    M(1,1) = 0.5-3;
    M(1,2) = 3-(2*0.5);
    M(1,3) = -0.5;

    M(2,0) = -0.5;
    M(2,1) = 0;
    M(2,2) = 0.5;
    M(2,3) = 0;

    M(3,0) = 0;
    M(3,1) = 1;
    M(3,2)=0;
    M(3,3)=0;

      ArrayXXf T(1,4);



         T(0,0) = t*t*t; //you can't cube a float, but you can get the same result by doing this
         T(0,1) = t*t;
         T(0,2) = t;
         T(0,3)=1;
         //now the T matrix is filled
         ArrayXXf TM(1,4);

        TM(0,0) = (T(0,0) * M(0,0)) + (T(0,1) * M(1,0)) + (T(0,2) * M(2,0)) + (T(0,3) * M(0,3));
        TM(0,1) = (T(0,0) * M(0,1)) + (T(0,1) * M(1,1)) + (T(0,2) * M(2,1)) + (T(0,3) * M(3,1));
        TM(0,2) = (T(0,0) * M(0,2)) + (T(0,1) * M(1,2)) + (T(0,2) * M(2,2)) + (T(0,3) * M(3,2));
        TM(0,3) = (T(0,0) * M(0,3)) + (T(0,1) * M(1,3)) + (T(0,2) * M(2,3)) + (T(0,3) * M(3,3));
        //first multiply T amd M




        GLfloat TMP;

        TMP = (TM(0,0) * P(0,0)) + (TM(0,1) *P(1,0)) + (TM(0,2) * P(2,0)) + (TM(0,3) * P(3,0));



      return TMP;
} 


void fillArrays()
{


    /*  zRot = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6);
        yRot = catSpline(1, 4, 6, 7);
        xRot = catSpline(6, 3, 2, 6);

        xArr = catSpline(9, 4, 3, 10);
        yArr = catSpline(1, 2, 4, 8);
        zArr = catSpline(8, 3, 1, 3);*/

    for(int j=0; j>=100; j++)
    {
        xArr[j] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, t);
        t+=0.1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i>=100; i++)
    {
        yArr[i] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, ty);
        ty+=0.1;
    }
    for(int k=0; k>=100; k++)
    {
        xArr[k] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, tz);
        tz += 0.1;
    }

    for(int a=0; a>=100; a++)
    {
        xRot[a] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, rx);
        rx += 0.1;
    }

    for(int b=0; b>=100; b++)
    {
        yRot[b] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, ry);
        rz += 0.1;
    }

    for(int c=0; c>=100; c++)
    {
        zRot[c] = catSpline(2, 4, 5, 6, rz);
        rz += 0.1;
    }


}
```

The way I use these three functions is in a loop called Render, I set up OpenGL for displaying an animation of a teapot model, call `fillArrays()`, and then attempt to store the result of a single `fixedAngle` call (using a few entries form the arrays filled in just before) in a new array called foo. This seems to be the cause of the errors, with foo only containing a pointer address rather than pointing to the actual array so I can use it. This is the code I'm using to call these functions:

```
fillArrays();

    GLfloat * foo;
    foo = (GLfloat *) malloc(16*sizeof(GLfloat));

    foo = fixedAngle(xArr[tp], yArr[tp], zArr[tp], xRot[tp], yRot[tp], zRot[tp]);

    glLoadMatrixf(foo);
```

After having used multiple print statements to print out the results of my functions, I know that the problem has to be how I set up the pointers somewhere. Can anyone help me return the array correctly?

Please note: if some of the matrix syntax seems unfammiliar, it's because I'm using a c++ library called Eigen to do some of the matrix math. Once again, after having rigorously printed out the results of the functions, I know that the functions that use Eigen syntax are producing the right values.

Comment: You don't include enough information to even attempt to reproduce the problem you report.  Random code snippets are very hard to analyze

Comment: One thing that seems odd to me is that you allocate memory for `foo`, then **immediately** assigned other allocated memory to `foo`. That's sure to be a memory leak one day. That's likely not the cause of your error, though.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: I recommend you switch to using/returning a `std::vector<GLfloat>` - as long as you use `push_back`, or give the constructor an appropriate initial size or explicitly call `resize()` before indexing with `[]`, you basically can't screw it up.  Hmmm.....

Comment: Just curious. What does `x<<1, 0, 0, 0,...;` do?

Comment: x<<1, 0, 0, 0,...; is filling up an array. Eigen makes it simple to access specific value sin an array and fill it up, and also makes array multiplication a lot easier. As long as the arrays have compatible dimensions and you've initialized the values, multiplying arrays in eigen is a simple as x*y.

Comment: To Tony D, could you perhaps show how I can do this in a formal answer to the question?

Comment: @Maria-Andersado: added below.  You may have other bugs in your overall program though - don't expect this to fix everything....

Answer (score 1):

You can replace...

```
GLfloat * arr;
arr = (GLfloat *) malloc(16*sizeof(GLfloat));
```

...with...

```
std::vector<GLfloat> arr(16);
```

...or even directly initialise it instead of copying elements afterwards...

```
std::vector<GLfloat> arr { fin(0,0), fin(0,1), fin(0,2), fin(0,3),
                           fin(1,0), fin(1,1), fin(1,2), fin(1,3),
                           fin(2,0), fin(2,1), fin(2,2), fin(2,3),
                           fin(3,0), fin(3,1), fin(3,2), fin(3,3) };
```

...which - FWIW - could also be done like this...

```
std::vector<GLfloat> arr;
for (int a = 0; a <= 3; ++a)
    for (int b = 0; b <= 3; ++b)
        arr.push_back(fin(a,b));
```

With any of the above, you'll need to change the return type correspondingly...

```
std::vector<GLfloat> fixedAngle(
    GLfloat initialX, GLfloat initialY, GLfloat initialZ,
    GLfloat rotX, GLfloat rotY, GLfloat rotZ)
{
    ...
```

...then you can call `fixedAngle` and use `foo` like this:

```
fillArrays();
std::vector<GLfloat> foo = fixedAngle(xArr[tp], yArr[tp], zArr[tp],
                                     xRot[tp], yRot[tp], zRot[tp]);
glLoadMatrixf(foo.data()); // or `&foo[0]` if you prefer...
```

Comment: I just want to know how I should change the return type. (I'm still new to c++).

Comment: @Maria-Andersado: if you "just" want to change the return type, you're at a dead end: your function's already using a `GLfloat*` to address the `malloc`ed memory, and has the right return type to return that to the calling code.  So changing "just" the return type will tend to stop your program compiling (unless you make a useless change like to `void*`).  (My answer is trying to show you a way to avoid pointers so you can be productive writing robust code, despite being new to C++, and avoiding explicit application-level memory allocation is considered best practice even for C++ experts....)

Comment: No, it's just that you said that using your recommended sollutions would require me to change the return type. I'm still learning the C++ syntax and wanted to know how I could change the return type so it would match something like std::vector<GLfloat>

Comment: @Maria-Andersado: oh - with you now; where I said `std::vector<GLfloat> fixedAngle(...` - that's the text that should replace your old `GLfloat * fixedAngle(...`.  The function return type appears before the function name and arguments.